# How To Parse a URL in J2ME

Tags: java, url, parsing, java-me

I'm trying to extract the query's name-value pairs from a URL using J2ME, but it doesn't make it easy. J2ME doesn't have the java.net.URL class nor does String have a split method.

Is there a way to extract name-value pairs from a URL using J2ME? Any open source implementations would be welcome too.

Comment: Make sure you take into consideration encoded chars if your going to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I like [kchau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22371/kchau) answer but i just changed the data structure from two arrays to one Hashtable.  This will also help if the number of URL parameters is unknown.

```
    String url = "http://www.so.com?name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3";

    Hashtable values = new Hashtable();

    int s = url.indexOf("?");  
    int e = 0;

    while (s != -1) {
        e = url.indexOf("=", s);              
        String name = url.substring(s + 1, e);
        s = e + 1;                            
        e = url.indexOf("&", s);              

        if (e < 0) {
            values.put(name, url.substring(s, url.length()));
        } else {        
            values.put(name, url.substring(s, e));
        }

        s = e;
    }

    for (Enumeration num = values.keys(); num.hasMoreElements();) {
            String key = (String)num.nextElement();
            System.out.println(key + "  " + values.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: A hashtable<String, String> isn't right though; you have to allow for multiple parameters with the same name.  name1=value1&name1=value2 is perfectly valid.  You want something more like Guava's Multimap.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab at it, some similarity to David's answer.

```
    String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com?name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3";

    String[] names  = new String[10];
    String[] values = new String[10];

    int s = url.indexOf("?");  // Get start index of first name
    int e = 0, idx = 0;

    while (s != -1) {
        e = url.indexOf("=", s);              // Get end index of name string
        names[idx] = url.substring(s+1, e);
        s = e + 1;                            // Get start index of value string
        e = url.indexOf("&", s);              // Get index of next pair

        if (e < 0)  // Last pair
            values[idx] = url.substring(s, url.length());
        else        // o.w. keep storing
            values[idx] = url.substring(s, e);

        s = e;
        idx++;
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        System.out.println(names[x] +" = "+ values[x]);
```

Tested it, and I think it works. Hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Java JDK is open-source, you could also borrow the java URL class from the main JDK and add it to your project. This would let you use the same implementation from Java SE:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/URL.java.html

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, it'd go something like this (warning: untested):

```
String url = ...;
int s = url.indexOf("?") + 1;
while (s > 0) {
    int e = url.indexOf("=", s);
    String name = url.substring(s, e), value;
    s = e + 1;
    e = url.indexOf("&", s);
    if (e < 0)
        value = url.substring(s, e);
    else
        value = url.substring(s, e);
    // process name, value
    s = e;
}
```

Query strings can technically be separated by a semicolon instead of an ampersand, like `name1=value1;name2=value2;...`, although I've never seen it done in practice.  If that's a concern for you, I'm sure you can fix up the code for it.

Comment: I think there's a minor problem, when you iterate through the loop, won't the name and value strings get overwritten?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comment you have in there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a J2ME implementation that doesn't have java.net.URL?
It's part of the [Connected Device Configuration](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr218/java/net/URL.html), [Foundation Profile](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr219/java/net/URL.html), [Personal Basis Profile](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr217/java/net/URL.html), and [Personal Profile](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr216/java/net/URL.html)...

Edit: For the record, these are the CDC 1.1.2 links, but according to [JSR36](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr036/), CDC 1.0 also has a java.net.URL class.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think CDC 1.1.2 is to be found much in the wild. CDC 1.1 lacks those JSRs, AFAICT.

Comment: According to JSR 36 (http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr036/), CDC 1.0 also has a java.net.URL class.

Comment: CDC is not wide spread, most modern J2ME implementations only support CLDC 1.1, with a lot of CLDC 1.0 phones still out there too.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I would have thought manufacturers would avoid using something with Limited in its name, but I'm not a manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Also, please note, that url params are URL-Encoded, so you may need to decode them first (how to do it is another question)

I get parameters in this way:

```
public String getUrlParam(String url, String param)
{
    int startIndex = url.indexOf(""+param+"=");
    if (startIndex == -1)
        return null;
    int length = (""+param+"=").length();
    int endIndex = url.indexOf("&", startIndex+length);
    if (endIndex == -1)
        endIndex = url.length();
    return URLDecode(url.substring(startIndex+length, endIndex));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A URL Encoder/Decoder is really simple and easy to write. You can also look up any open source HTML to WML transcoder code on the internet and modify it. Shouldnt be too hard.

Comment: stackoverflow is filled with halfbaked wrong answers to this question.